# Procmail Couldn't create or rename temp file, not receiving mails

Tags: centos, postfix, procmail

I cant receive any mail from outside, here all my settings and outputs:
More informations are in the Procmail output, all the permissions is for the user and I dont see anything wrong here...

Im using Virtualmin.

**postconf -d**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
allow_percent_hack = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
compatibility_level = 2
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
meta_directory = /etc/postfix
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, mail.$mydomain
mydomain = domain.com
myhostname = ns1.domain.com
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix32u-3.2.5/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix32u-3.2.5/samples
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/dependent
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
shlib_directory = /usr/lib64/postfix
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_banner = $myhostname
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/certs/domain.com.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/domain.com.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
soft_bounce = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

**procmail.log**

```
procmail: Couldn't create or rename temp file "/home/user/Maildir/tmp/1525034649.14276_0.ns1.domain.com"
procmail: Couldn't create or rename temp file "/home/user/Maildir/tmp/1525034649.14276_1.ns1.domain.com"
From usermail@gmail.com  Sun Apr 29 17:44:08 2018
Subject: JDIadjsdidads
Folder: **Bounced** 3986
Time:1525034649 From:usermail@gmail.com To:user@domain.com User:user Size:4291 Dest:/etc/webmin/virtual-server/clam-wrapper.pl /bin/clamdscan --config-file /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf Mode:None
```

**maillog**

```
Apr 29 17:44:06 ns1 postfix/smtpd[14270]: connect from mail-wr0-f178.google.com[209.85.128.178]
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 postfix/smtpd[14270]: 4E84B8D: client=mail-wr0-f178.google.com[209.85.128.178]
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 postfix/cleanup[14274]: 4E84B8D: message-id=<CABcH+u=RCMXn2d44iXVnr9ZS27_DUPy=CATH81BG7YrhEKaz2w@mail.gmail.com>
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 opendkim[1186]: 4E84B8D: mail-wr0-f178.google.com [209.85.128.178] not internal
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 opendkim[1186]: 4E84B8D: not authenticated
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 opendkim[1186]: 4E84B8D: no signing domain match for 'gmail.com'
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 opendkim[1186]: 4E84B8D: no signing subdomain match for 'gmail.com'
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 postfix/qmgr[1291]: 4E84B8D: from=<usermail@gmail.com>, size=3902, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 29 17:44:08 ns1 postfix/smtpd[14270]: disconnect from mail-wr0-f178.google.com[209.85.128.178] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 spamd[11080]: spamd: connection from localhost [::1]:60686 to port 783, fd 6
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 spamd[11080]: spamd: setuid to user succeeded
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 spamd[11080]: spamd: processing message <CABcH+u=RCMXn2d44iXVnr9ZS27_DUPy=CATH81BG7YrhEKaz2w@mail.gmail.com> for user:1002
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 spamd[11080]: spamd: clean message (-0.1/5.0) for user:1002 in 0.5 seconds, 3986 bytes.
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 spamd[11080]: spamd: result: . 0 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,RCVD_IN_MSPIKE_H2,SPF_PASS scantime=0.5,size=3986,user=user,uid=1002,required_score=5.0,rhost=localhost,raddr=::1,rport=60686,mid=<CABcH+u=RCMXn2d44iXVnr9ZS27_DUPy=CATH81BG7YrhEKaz2w@mail.gmail.com>,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 postfix/local[14275]: 4E84B8D: to=<user@ns1.domain.com>, orig_to=<user@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=2.8, delays=1.6/0.01/0/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME)
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 postfix/qmgr[1291]: 4E84B8D: removed
Apr 29 17:44:09 ns1 spamd[11036]: prefork: child states: II
```

**ls -l /home/user/Maildir/**

```
total 16
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Apr 29 16:59 cur
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Apr 29 16:59 new
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 27 Apr 29 16:59 subscriptions
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Apr 29 16:59 tmp
```

**ls -l /home/user/Maildir/tmp/**

```
total 0
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                          990M     0  990M   0% /dev
tmpfs                            1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            1000M  8.5M  992M   1% /run
tmpfs                            1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root            13G  1.9G  9.7G  17% /
/dev/vda1                         488M   94M  359M  21% /boot
/dev/vdb1                         9.8G   37M  9.2G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/centos-tmp            2.0G  6.1M  1.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/centos-var            5.8G  519M  5.0G  10% /var
/dev/mapper/centos-var_www        976M  2.6M  907M   1% /var/www
/dev/mapper/centos-var_tmp        2.0G  6.1M  1.8G   1% /var/tmp
/dev/mapper/centos-var_log        7.8G   59M  7.3G   1% /var/log
/dev/mapper/centos-var_log_audit  3.9G   29M  3.6G   1% /var/log/audit
tmpfs                             200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/0
```

**fstab**

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=e25b5faf-e6de-44b1-8c65-58141c9b887c /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-tmp  /tmp                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-var  /var                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-var_log /var/log                ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-var_log_audit /var/log/audit          ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-var_tmp /var/tmp                ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-var_www /var/www                ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/vdb1 /home ext4 quota,seclabel,grpquota,usrquota,data=ordered,noatime,rw 0 2
```

Comment: what is result of command `ls -ld /tmp`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Here is the output `drwxrwxrwt. 14 root root 4096 Apr 30 10:05 /tmp`

Comment: Does Procmail run with correct permissions? Do you have an `/etc/procmailrc`?

Comment: @tripleee Yes i have this file with this permissions `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 403 Apr 29 17:26 /etc/procmailrc` and the procmail bin permissions are `-rwxr-sr-x. 1 root mail 107984 Nov 28 19:51 /usr/bin/procmail`

Comment: Looks like your `/etc/procmailrc` was recently modified. What's in it?

Comment: Can you figure out which user Procmail is running as when this delivery fails?

Comment: @tripleee I dont modify /etc/procmailrc, I think that is because my server is a fresh install. And how can I figure out wich user is running? Is not root? I will try to reinstall OS and virtualmin again.